# How can I get unacked messages in rabbitmq in swift language?

Tags: swift, rabbitmq

In java, I'm getting unacked messages with `channel.basicRecover(true)`, Is there anything like this in swift?

I'm also getting this error when I use `channel.recover()` in swift version.

```
allocator = <RMQMultipleChannelAllocator: 0x15c7f28a0>> 
error: Error Domain=com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-objc-client Code=8 "Expected RMQChannelOpenOk, got (null)." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Expected RMQChannelOpenOk, got (null).}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`channel.recover()` is really a private API for doing automatic connection recovery. We've recently documented this here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client/blob/master/RMQClient/RMQChannel.h#L98

We currently don't have `basicRecover` support, like Java. If you have a use for it, please file an issue: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client/issues